# JS. Если в качестве ключа свойства объекта указать переменную

Tags: javascript

Если в качестве ключа свойства объекта указать переменную, то ключ свойства будет ссылаться на эту переменную, или значение переменной скопируется в ключ?

Comment: Значение, содержащееся в переменной, будет преобразовано в строку, и эта строка будет использоваться как ключ

Comment: Никакой связи с исходной переменной не будет

Answer (score 3):

Вы вполне можете это проверить:

```js
let x = 'abc';

let o = { [x]: 1 }; // → Object { abc: 1 }

x = 'def';

console.log( o ); // → Object { abc: 1 }

console.log( o[x] ); // o.def → undefined
```

Comment: Для полноты картины ещё можно про Symbol написать

Comment: @AlexeyTen  С символами, увы, очень мало работал.  Можете отредактировать.